# Raster plots - the higher the resolution, the smaller the text

Tags: r, plot, raster, resolution, text-size

I need to make some plots with raster and I am currently facing some issues.
I would like to save my plots at 1920x1080 resolution.
I have noticed that when setting the resolution to this (which is higher than the default), the font is getting smaller. So probably the "cex" commands regulating the font is linked to pixels.

To demonstrate this I wrote the plotting script for 720p and for 1080p

720p code:

```
  for (i in 1:length(pfts)) {
    png(filename=paste0("P_", pfts[[i]], ".png"), width=1280, height=720, units="px")
    plot(subset(P_stack, i), 
        main=paste0("Global Leaf Area Index (LAI): ", pfts[i]), 
         cex.main=1.8, legend.args=list(text='Leaf Area Index', side=4, line=2.5, cex=1.2), 
         xlab=list("° Longitude", cex=1.3), ylab=list("° Latitude", cex=1.3), cex.axis=1.2)
    dev.off()
  }
```

And the 720p plot looks as follows:
[720p plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsErt.png)

1080p code:

```
  for (i in 1:length(pfts)) {
    png(filename=paste0("P_", pfts[[i]], ".png"), width=1920, height=1080, units="px")
    plot(subset(P_stack, i), 
         main=paste0("Global Leaf Area Index (LAI): ", pfts[i]), 
         cex.main=1.8, legend.args=list(text='Leaf Area Index', side=4, line=2.5, cex=1.2), 
         xlab=list("° Longitude", cex=1.3), ylab=list("° Latitude", cex=1.3), cex.axis=1.2)
    dev.off()
  }
```

And the 1080p plot looks as follows:
[1080p plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXPnf.png)

As described, you can see that the text gets smaller with the same numbers. However, if I would like to make the text bigger it starts cutting into the graph and cutting the text off at the sides instead of scaling the graph accordingly.

[1080p plot with double font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciVP6.png)

Has anybody else faced this issue and if yes, knows how to make the graph adapt to the font size while keeping the resultion high?
And also does anybody know how to adapt the legend number scale font size?

I would appreciate any informative answers. Thanks!

Comment: The cex argument controls font size. You have it set to a constant value, so font size will remain the same.

Comment: Use `res = ` (resolution) to adjust.

Comment: @at80 I know, hence the 1080p with 2x font size example.

Comment: @Werner where in the code would I implement the res, how would I do it and what does it affect? Could you please specify?

Comment: you could try `aggregate(raster, fact = 2` to increase the resolution by a factor of 2. Although, you can also try `res(raster) <- c(720, 1080)` to individually change the `(x,y)` resolution although this may impact your values and dimensions. You could also use `resample` and shift the resolution from another raster to your current raster. So by creating a dummy raster with those resolutions then using `resample(raster1, raster2, method = "ngb")`